# Pushing multiple MySQL databases into ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have a Single-tenant SAAS architecture (which is a B2B e-commerce app) and I am trying to create a new B2C customer application. As a consumer, I would like to search through all the client databases for products (with available inventory) and place the order to a specific B2B client that is selected based on the search results.

I have selected ElasticSearch for product aggregation and I plan to push the data with LogStash by connecting with all the MySQL client databases.

My question is, is it possible to manage multiple (thousands of) MySQL connections with LogStash? I will be doing it with JDBC plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html.

How do I create the logstash.conf file? Do I create a single file for each DB connection or can I create it dynamically (I have a list of all DB connections)?

Suggest me if there is a better approach at doing it.

Comment: Can you be clearer in your question please. Are you asking how to configure logstash? You've also tagged Apache Kafka. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Yes. How to configure logstash for multiple databases? I am new to this and I am not sure if I am in the right direction.

Comment: I shouldn't have tagged Kafka since I didn't mention it in the question. removing it.

Comment: well since I'm here :-D … I would suggest taking a look at Mysql -> Kafka with Kafka Connect and Debezium (https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/), and then Kafka -> Elasticsearch with Kafka Connect (https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch-video)

Comment: Yes, using Kafka connect /debezium could have been a separate question. My main concern is to connect multiple DBs. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If it's the same logical entity then you'd stream all of them into the same Kafka topic (optionally adding in a source metadata field on the way in with Single Message Transform), and then you stream that one topic to Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

I am using something similar with various databases. I currently have a .conf file for each base. Each .conf file has x amount of jdbc input.
For example:

```
* Base_001: my_db_001.conf
* Base_002: mi_db_002.conf
....
* Base_00x: my_db_00x.conf
```

Also, if you want you can modify the pipeline.yml file to divide the configuration files or make it look for them with a pattern, example:

```
- pipeline.id: my_dbs
  path.config: "/home/user/logstash/*.conf"
```

As for making the dynamic connections, I have not been able to do it and as far as I could consult and test, it is not possible.

If it is not what you were consulting, please consult and I will help you.